# LambdaExpression constructor

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I saw code like below. My questions are:

1> `()=>Name` what does this mean?

2> Is `Expression<Func<>>` the same as `Expression<TDelegate>`? How is `()=>Name` cast to `Expression<Func<>>` and which constructor is used? Most Expression classes don't have public constructors. How does C# compiler convert from Lambda to Expression?

3> What is the performance cost of the Parse function?

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public void Start()
    {
        Parse(()=>Name);
    }

    public string Parse<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp)
    {
        var mexp = (System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return mexp == null ? "" : mexp.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should measure to answer #3.

Answer (score 5):

1. That is a lambda that takes no arguments, but results in a `String`.
2. No. `TDelegate` is a template argument. `Func<T>` is a concrete type that satisfies the `TDelegate`'s constraints. The C# compiler will convert the lambda into the appropriate type at compile time.
3. You should measure in order to answer this question.

Comment: Why it recognize Name property in my class? And in this case, what type the C# complier converts this Lambda to?

Comment: @Helic that's because it is closed upon.

Comment: so does it mean I can use Parse(()=>{return name;}), but it gives me another exception "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". Also, please see my edit to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So `()=>Name` is a lambda function. It is basically a function that returns the `Name` property. In your case this thing is a `Func<string>` by type.

All that changes a little because you hand it over to a field that is defined as `Expression<Func<T>>`. In your case you give a `Expression<Func<string>>`. Basically that makes the lambda function to a expression of a lambda function that gives you not the result of the function but the structure.

Usually a structure like this is used to get the name of a property in a safe way. For example to prevent a obfuscator or a accidental renaming to mess with your code.

Comment: " hand it over " do you mean cast?

Comment: I have no idea what the C# compiler does at this point. `()=>Name` is a `Func<string>` and it turns to a `Expression<Func<string>>`. Sadly I can only tell you that it works. I can't tell you why.